# Feature Rich Mapping Service for local deployment (VM) & web deployment

Tags: openstreetmap, routing, server, mapping, localhost

Since initially posting this, I have stumbled accross solutions for some of my sub-questions. This is the updated question, with fewer requirements.

I would like to create a mapping service using OpenStreetMaps (OSM) data to meet the following requirements:

- **Routing**

  - **offline**, for local testing & **online** (when deployed to the web, hosting it myself)
  - **mode:** walking, driving & bicycle
  - **data:** route geometry/shape & driving instructions / directions)
  - **criteria:** shortest, fastet, etc.
- **Geocoding** & **Reverse Geocoding**

Ideally, this would all be provided by a single solution, but combining multiple 3rd party projects into a single solution would be the next best thing.

**QUESTIONS:**

Is there a single solution incorporating the features above?

Alternatively, can someone recommend several solutions for the various features?

Solutions I have considered so far:

- **GraphHopper:** https://graphhopper.com/
- **Valhalla:** https://github.com/valhalla

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  As it stands I think your question is too broad for our focussed Q&A format because you are stating a series of requirements and then asking for a solution to be recommended.

Comment: It's not really feasible to throw everything together into a single application. Routing, geocoding and rendering are completely different tasks, requiring different database structures in order to be fast and efficient. Also, running all these tasks on a single server won't be feasible for the same reasons.

Comment: Also have a look into nominatim and photon for (reverse) geocoding